# Keeping Humanity Relevant Without Going Too Far?

Tags: science-fiction, humans, aliens, interspecies-relations

Some fictional works with other sentient races, especially sci-fi stories (like Mass Effect for example), tend to say humanity is "special", or even outright "superior", in some way to keep them relevant. How can we keep humanity relevant without quite going so far?

Comment: This seems a bit more like a question for Writting

Comment: Define "relevant".

Comment: As @StephenG says, "what's relevant?"  In the *Valérian and Laureline* comic series humanity is just another one of the thousands of species out there.  We have our contributors and our leeches, our statesmen and our rogues.  We're just another bean in the chili of life.  That's why we need you to define what you mean by "relevant," because it seems you want them to be special in some way without them being special at all.

Answer (score 3):

**Unique Instead of "Superior"**

We're a good well rounded out species that is better than some at some things and worse than others at some things. But, we are of course unique, we have some inherent cultural traits that make interesting just like every other race has traits that make them unique and interesting. Rather than trying to evaluate things by some sort of black and white good/bad or "better than" sliding scale we are simply viewed as a member of the greater cosmic whole with our own flaws and weaknesses as well as gifts and strengths to contribute to the greater intergalactic society.